# Copy element of nested std::vector to std::vector

Tags: c++11, vector

I have encountered problem in copying the element of nested std::vector to another std::vector.

Example 1

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo;
std::vector<int> temp;
std::vector<int> goo;

temp.push_back(12345);
foo.push_back(temp);
goo = foo[0]; //error
```

Example 2

```
temp.clear();
for(int i = 0; i<foo[0].size(); i++) {temp.push_back(foo[0][i])};
goo = temp; //error
```

Thus, can i know where is the problem and what should i do to copy the element of a nested vector to another vector??

EDIT:
The actual scenario would be i have nested vector of cv::Point

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> found_contour;
```

and would like to copy the element inside a `std::vector<cv::Point>` in a struct.

```
struct Contours
{
    std::vector<cv::Point> contour;
    cv::RotatedRect minRect;
    cv::RotatedRect minEllipse;
}
```

Code Snippet:

```
cv::findContours(result,found_contour,found_hierachy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cv::Point(0,0));

std::vector<Contours> contour_struct;
contour_struct.reserve(found_contour.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < found_contour.size(); i++)
{
    contour_struct[i].contour = found_contour[i];
    contour_struct[i].minRect = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(found_contour[i]));
}
```

Comment: There is no `foo[0]` in your code, as you didn't insert any vector object into `foo` yet.

Comment: @nwp, ya, sorry for my mistake, i have edited the snippet

Comment: @nwp, sorry for my mistake, edited it already. Thanks

Comment: First example is good now and will not cause an error. Check `found_contour.size()` to make sure it is not empty.

Comment: @nwp, Thanks, but i am still having an error with `contour_struct[i].contour = found_contour[i];`, any ideas??

Comment: `contour_struct` is a `vector<Contours>`? Show a complete example that should compile but doesn't. Without seeing the code it is hard to guess what went wrong.

Comment: @nwp, `contour_struct` is a `vector<Contours>`, Thanks, the code compiled ok but stopped working when encountered the line of `contour_struct[i].contour = found_contour[i];`

Comment: Maybe `found_contour.size() > contour_struct.size()` and thats why it crashed? `contour_struct.reserve()` does not resize `contour_struct`. You probably want `contour_struct.resize()` instead.

Comment: @nwp, i have tried to allocate more space in `contour_struct.size()` and it still crashed....Thanks.

Comment: @nwp, thanks alot, i think you are right, the program didn't crash if i used resize instead of reserve. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cv::findContours(result,found_contour,found_hierachy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cv::Point(0,0));

std::vector<Contours> contour_struct;
contour_struct.reserve(found_contour.size()); //<-----problem

for (size_t i = 0; i < found_contour.size(); i++)
{
    contour_struct[i].contour = found_contour[i];
    contour_struct[i].minRect = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(found_contour[i]));
}
```

`vector::reserve` only aquires space internally so that `push_back` does not run out of space. It does not actually add more objects into the `vector`. You can use this line instead:

```
contour_struct.resize(found_contour.size());
```

which will make sure that `contour_struct` is the right size.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer